# Implement AvgPool Instead Of MaxPool In Segmentation Models

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

Is it possible to implement AvgPool layer in the segmentation model architectures such as UNet, SegNet and etc. instead of MaxPool layer? And what would be the effect of that on the model's performance?

And even does it require any changes in the structure of decoder or encoder like as upsampling method (ConvTranspose or UpSampling) or anything else?

Comment: Is this for pytorch?

Comment: Sorry, didn't get what you mean? As you know, most of the segementation models consist of encoder and decoder, and encoder extract feature maps and downsample the images, for this operation will use MaxPool layer. Now is it possible to change this type of layer into AvgPool? and then Will AvgPool require any changes in decoder or Upsample methods (ConvolutionTranspose Or UpSampling layer)? @toyotaSupra

Comment: I know, but i don't get what do you mean that you said is this for pytorch? but my question was just about structure of segmentation models architecture.

Answer (score 0):

You could replace maxpooling for other pooling layers without architecture incompatibilities if you keep the size of the kernel (filter) unchanged. The effect on model's performance depends mainly on data and extracted features as states in [This article](https://medium.com/@bdhuma/which-pooling-method-is-better-maxpooling-vs-minpooling-vs-average-pooling-95fb03f45a9#:%7E:text=Average%20pooling%20method%20smooths%20out,lighter%20pixels%20of%20the%20image.) an AVG pooling can help on low frecuency details and a Maxpooling can be used to detect sharper ones.

The encoder / decoder structure doesn't need to be changed.

Comment: So as you mentioned above, MaxPool layer could detect sharper details, and based on segmentation approach, how well the sharp edges were detected, will improve model performance and so MaxPool layer would be more accuracte than the other types of pooling layers to detect the object outlines.

Comment: Yeah, IMHO maxpooling will work best in semantic segmentation and object detection because we are guiding the network to learn morphological features, extracted from sharp edges and object outlines.